# ModuleNotFoundException: Unable to deploy war on Jboss EAP 7

Tags: war, jboss-eap-7

Installed jBoss EAP 7.0 and trying to deploy a .war file but getting below error. I tried to search for the error but failed to understand Explanations about it.

```
03:13:23,229 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-7) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.module.service."deployment.MMSBackOffice.war".main: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.module.service."deployment.MMSBackOffice.war".main: WFLYSRV0179: Failed to load module: deployment.MMSBackOffice.war:main
        at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:91)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.modules.ModuleNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.deploy.api:main
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.addPaths(Module.java:1092)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.link(Module.java:1448)
        at org.jboss.modules.Module.relinkIfNecessary(Module.java:1476)
        at org.jboss.modules.ModuleLoader.loadModule(ModuleLoader.java:225)
        at org.jboss.as.server.moduleservice.ModuleLoadService.start(ModuleLoadService.java:68)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Does your deployment have a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` descriptor?

Comment: Is your issue resolved?Did you try add it explicitly to `jboss-deploymet-structure.xml`?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this module inside `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` dependencies explicitly and place it inside your war `WEB-INF`then try this once again.